# Why does Visual Studio automatically excludes files from Pending Changes for template projects like MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

VS2017, TFS2017

When I create a template MVC solution and add it to source control, I notice VS automatically excludes a large number of files.  Why is that?

I have always promoted those exclusions, but it occurred to me the VS designers may be setting up defaults this way for a good reason and I don't need to manually promote these exclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's different reasons depending on what exactly you're talking about being excluded. Generally speaking, you should not commit things like user preferences, local databases, etc. Nuget packages should never be committed, since these can be restored easily after the solution is downloaded, and you really don't want to be managing updates to all the Nuget packages you're using in your source control.

Comment: In this case, I notice every single one of the excluded changes are in the packages folder which makes them fall into the category you are speaking of.  Thx.